# Download apk using PHP

Tags: php, android

I want to download APK which is placed in my Windows server. The file exists. PHP script is given below

```
<?php
 $file = '/45.34.14.285/n1/n.apk'; //not public folder
  if (file_exists($file)) {
     header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
     header('Content-Type: application/vnd.android.package-archive');
     header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
     header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
     header('Expires: 0');
     header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
     header('Pragma: public');
     header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
     ob_clean();
     flush();
     readfile($file);
     exit;
 }
else
{
echo 'No File Found';
}
?>
```

But it returns

> 'No File Found'

Comment: does this php code really downloads the apk, like your question is telling us? Or do you want to serve apk, so that the user can download and install them?

Comment: i want the user to download the apk and install them

Comment: So you better edit your question to make this clear. The more care you take for the text and title of the question, the better are the answer you get.

Comment: `'/45.34.14.285/n1/n.apk'` does not look like a valid windows file path